# Show that the set of zero of a polynomial of $n$ variables has dimension $n-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

The set of zeros in $\mathbb{C}$ for a polynomial of one variable and of any degree is the set of points, i.e. dimension 0.

I have seen a few examples, e.g. in the book *Complex Analysis* by Freitag or other books, shows that the set of zeros of a polynomial of two variables (domain $\mathbb{C^2}$) is an curve, i.e. dimension 1. But none proves if it valid in general.

Is it true and if so how to show that the set of zero of a polynomial of $n$ variables has dimension $n-1$?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "dimension" (the zero set is not a manifold in general), you can use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I have studied implicit function theorem in real analysis. I don't know how to generalize it for $\mathbb{C^n}$. By "dimension" I mean that for example the set of all zeros of a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is always is a 'surface' in $\mathbb{C^n}$. I even don't know how to define a surface in $\mathbb{C^n}$, even though I know the case for $\mathbb{R^n}$!

Comment: You don't need to generalize it, just think of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. A complex polynomial has a real and complex part so its zero locus is the zero locus of two real functions (in fact polynomials).